# How to display div content in the same format? The content is taken from Database

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a Template that is stored in DB.
I want to display the template in a Div

I used the below code to populate the template in Div.

document.getElementById('dvPreview').innerHTML = Template;
I used Ajax POST for getting the Template.

The Actual template is

Dear Arun

Welcome to Company

Your Email ID : arun@company.com

Employee Code : E6498

Regading

Team .

But the div Content shows like below

Dear Arun Welcome to Company Your Email ID : arun@company.com Employee Code : E6498 Regading Team

The mail content is also wrong.

How can I correct this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check with this.

```
Template.Replace("\n", "< br/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

The template should be html formatted.. You should first save formatted template in database

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to change returns to `<br/>`'s. You can do it by calling

```
yourTemplate.replace(/\n/g,"<br />");
```

Answer (score 0):

First check is the Template is saving correctly in db. Now your problem is new line constant so you have to change the returns `"\n" (the new line)` with `<br />` before assigning it to div's innerhtml.

Try this (at client side with javascript)

```
Template.replace(/\n/g,"<br />");
```

At code behind you can do like this

```
Template.Replace("\n", "<br/>");
```